# Can I just install TeX Live to get ConTeXt?

Tags: texlive, context, windows

I have a hankering to try ConTeXt again.

I am normally a MikTeX user -- its on all my computers, except the linux ones (which generally use whatever is the the package manager).

Last time I used ConTeXt, I had to install a stand-alone, and had to do a bunch of shenanigans to get it working with the PATH.

I see these days ConTeXt is included in TeX Live,
and TeX Live is available for windows.

Does ConTeXt with TeX Live "just work"?

Comment: It works but it's always behind the stand-alone 'minimals' distribution: depends on what you need

Comment: For messing around and learning, and not having to deal with the manual being for not my version.

Comment: Do you want to use MkIV or MkII?

Comment: presumably MkIV, since it by definition must be better? why make MkIV if MkII was fine? (Possibly another question)

Comment: FYI: ConTeXt standalone just works under Windows. Just copy context to any location (without spaces in the path) or let the batch file do it for you, using rsync. After that just call context.exe. If you want, you can put the binary path into the PATH-variable to access context from anywhere.

Comment: I'm sure i used to have to do something odd to add context to my path, and remove miktex from my path, cos they can't both be in the path at the same time -- because miktex includes a broken copy of context (or something)

Comment: Years ago ConTeXt was also working in MikTeX, but then apparently MikTeX's author lost interest in packaging it properly when LuaTeX and MkIV came around and Hans did a few things his own way. You could consider putting more pressure to get ConTeXt back to MikTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version of ConTeXt in TeX Live 'just works' on Windows provided we are talking about the LuaTeX-based MkIV code. ConTeXt MkII needs a Ruby interpreter to run the wrapper script, and Windows systems do not typically have one installed. In contrast, MkIV only needs LuaTeX (the scripting part is written in Lua), so doesn't require any additions.

Note that ConTeXt in TeX Live is almost always behind that in the stand-alone ConTeXt distribution.